# Represent a Mixture with a Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, representation

I'm trying to represent a mixture in Django. Something like:

```
Chemical #1 - 50%
Chemical #2 - 30%
Chemical #3 - 20%
```

I figured I would use a wrapper called composition as follows:

```
class Composition(models.Model):
    """ Just a Wrapper """
    def save(...):
        #Validate ingredients add up to 100% and such


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    composition = models.ForeignKey('Composition',related_name='ingredients')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    percentage = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this. Keep in mind that I'm doing it like this so I can later use inlines in the Django admin. What do you guys recommend? Thanks a lot =)

Comment: don't you need a table to keep track of mixtures?  If so, this is a basic [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) relationship

Comment: @Dmitry what do you mean by keep track of mixtures? I have another model which has a onetoone relationship with a composition

Comment: Ok, I'll try with the ManyToMany relationship. I'll have to see if I can represent them the same way in the admin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me as though it would be preferable to keep a list of ingredients then reference those when you create your compositions, rather than entering the ingredient names each time. You could do it using a many to many relationship and a through table, like so:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Composition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='CompositionIngredient')

    def save(...):
        #Validate ingredients add up to 100% and such

class CompositionIngredient(models.Model):
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    proportion = models.DecimalField()
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more information.

EDIT: Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models) on how to deal with through tables in the admin interface.

Comment: That's pretty nice, didn't know you could do that. I'll give it a try and also rtfm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the complementary documentation, would give you more points if i could :)